# How do I include an externally maintained directory as a VisualStudio 2008 C# Project Resource?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

I have a  directory which contains externally maintained html help files for a Visual Studio 2008 project.  The directory could potentially contain an arbitrary number of files from build to build.  I know how to add a directory and files to a project including them through the Solution Explorer as required output (content), but in this case I want to always automatically include the specified html directory, all of its subfolders, and all of its files without having to set properties each time a file is added.

I do not want to set the "Build Action" and "Copy to Output Directory" properties each time each time there are changes in the help files.  Another constraint is I am using both an installation project (part of the same solution) and a ClickOnce install depending on the deployment environment.   This seems like it should be incredibly simple, but I have been unable to find an answer so far.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method you might look into is to tweak the .csproj file and add a post build target to do the copying.  This should be close to what you need:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DocumentationFiles Include="DocsDirectory\**\*"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(DocumentationFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="Output\Docs\"
    />
</Target>
```

Comment: That doesn't make them deployable content for ClickOnce.

Comment: I have not tested it with the installations, but on build that seems to be moving in the right direction.  However, it did not add the contents of the DocsDirectory recursively, it only pulled the top level files.  Also, it added that item group to the SolutionExplorer, but it had the top level files marked with the '/!\' and no subfolders.

Comment: @Hans Passant  You are correct, you'd have to do extra work to add the files into the manifest, but I think the AfterBuild strategy is still a solid approach.

Comment: @Skcussm I fixed the DocumentationFiles ItemGroup so it should now recurse properly.